# Do you listen to any podcasts about sound design?

Tags: podcasts, survey, recommendations, education

I regularly listen to a number of audio related podcasts, and I was wondering how popular they are and if I have missed any out.

Here's what I currently listen to: [AudioNowcast](http://nowcastnetwork.com/), [EM Podcasts](http://emusician.com/podcasts/), [Fistful of Cables](http://ffoc.tumblr.com/), [Gameaudio](http://www.gameaudiopodcast.com/), [The Home Recording Show](http://www.homerecordingshow.com/), [Home Studio Corner](http://www.homestudiocorner.com/), [Inside Home Recording](http://www.insidehomerecording.com/), [New Media Gear](http://www.newmediagear.com/), [Project Studio Network](http://projectstudionetwork.com/), [Recording Lounge](http://www.recordinglounge.blogspot.com/), [Ronan's Recording Show](http://ronansrecordingshow.com/), [Sessions with Slau](http://sessionswithslau.com/), [Shure Cast](http://shure.libsyn.com/), [Sine Language](http://www.sinelanguagepodcast.com/), [Sonic Talk](http://www.sonicstate.com/video/index.cfm?keyword=Sonic%20Talk), [Sound on Sound](http://www.soundonsound.com/podcast), and [Sounds Good](http://37hz.net/).

I enjoy listening to them all for different reasons.

What podcasts would you recommend?

[image: podcast icon]

Comment: Wow - the only one I've heard of is Sound On Sound. Thanks for the list!

Comment: Hehe, this is like a reverse question: you are the one giving all the (useful) information here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for this kind of thing for ages...

Answer (score 4):

*That's a good list, thanks... I only know a few from there. I'll have to update my subscriptions.*

Sound Ideas had a little series on the [sound effects](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/sound-ideas-sound-effects/id288810923). It sounds a bit like a big ad for them and isn't a great podcast, but worth a listen nonetheless.

To **not** answer your question, [RadioLab](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/wnycs-radiolab/id152249110) is not sound design related, but it has really good sound design. The way they use sound to help explain complicated concepts is very well done. It's one of my favorite.

Comment: RadioLab is such a stellar show. What a fantastic merging of sound design with talk-radio. This is my favorite kind of sound art: driven heavily by solid narrative.

Comment: @MtL Well put... 

Answer (score 3):

This is a really old question now but I thought I would add to the list. Rene Coronado (Dallas), Dustin Camilleri (Chicago) and myself (Toronto) have just released a new podcast that is all about sound design and audio post.  Its called Tonebenders.  If you want to take a listen to the first episode you can go to www.tonebenders.net and download it or grab the RSS feed to set up iTunes to subscribe.

Tonebenders' premiere episode, titled Origin Stories, introduces listeners to the show’s hosts.  Through in-depth discussions each host tells the story of how he ended up working in audio and the mistakes and triumphs experienced along the way.  Also, Dustin Camilleri talks about his recent trip to St. Cloud, MN, for the 2012 Kyma International Sound Symposium (K.I.S.S.).  Dustin  introduces listeners to the Kyma software/hardware system and offers his take on the conference.

Take a listen and let me know what you think or if you have any ideas for future episodes.

Answer (score 2):

I love putting on Touch Radio's podcast. A great mixture of nature recordings (from the likes of Chris Watson) to hour long ambient soundscapes.

Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across the [Binaural Airwaves](http://itpc://www.cyberears.com/podcasts/podcast_5392.xml) podcast, which purely features binaural recordings made by one guy in a load of different places. Seems interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another one you're not necessarily looking for is Apple's [Meet the Filmmaker](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/meet-the-filmmaker/id301899522). Though sound is rarely featured, most episodes offer great insight into the cinematic process. What I like best is hearing straight from directors what they were trying to achieve from certain parts of a story, then checking myself to see how close the sound team was to portraying it through the film's soundscape.